# webpack 2 dev server served from src

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

How should I set up my webpack config to run webpack-dev-server from `src` folder, not `dist`? I mean not only change path because then babel is not working. Now I have a problem that everything is served from bundle.js and I can't see for example where is an error. Here's my config file :

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname,'src')
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    port: 8000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `devserver.contentBase` to define where the server will serve content from, but this shouldn't be necessary unless you're trying to serve static files. The default is the current working directory and will be served from memory rather than from the `output.path`. Also, if you're not aware of it, your `output.publicPath` is making the content be served at `localhost:8000/dist/`

References:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase
http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html